# Reverse for 'blog-single' with keyword arguments

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create simple blog, I have a blog-home page that show the lastest puplished post and I want to open a single-blog page for each post but I encounter with this error : Reverse for 'blog-single' with keyword arguments '{'post_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

`['blog/blog/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']`

do you know how can I solve this ?

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW6I4.jpg)

[url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMdy0.jpg)

[blog-home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvxOv.jpg)

I check all the names and links in view, url and template but nothing was wrong.

from django.urls import path
from blog.views import *

url.py :

```
app_name = 'blog' 

urlpatterns = [
    path('',blog_home,name='blog-home'),
    path('blog/<int:post_id>/',blog_single, name = 'blog- 
single'),]
```

view.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import post 
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import F

def blog_home(request):
    current_time = timezone.now()
    posts = post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = current_time)
    context={'posts':posts}
    return render (request,'blog/blog-home.html',context)


def blog_single(request,post_id):
    current_time = timezone.now()
    post_obj = get_object_or_404(post,  pk = post_id, 
 published_date__lte=current_time)
    # Increment the counted_view for the specific post
    post_obj.counted_view = F('counted_view') + 1
    post_obj.save()
     context = {'post_obj': post_obj}
     return render(request, 'blog/blog-single.html', context)
```

blog-home.html :

```
{%for post in posts%}
<a class="posts-title" href="{% url 'blog:blog-single' 
post_id=post.id %}"><h3>{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) there is one example which is similar to yours and it passes only the value like this:

```
{% url 'blog:blog-single' post.id %}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: you have tag spaning in new line also